# How to align text within a div

Tags: html, css

I'm a newbie at HTML/CSS and have spent the past hour attempting to do something which is apparently beyond me. I have been trying to movie text within a div slightly upwards in order for it to be aligned with some images.

http://jsfiddle.net/xE2qJ

```
<div class='social-media-button'> <a href='www.facebook.com/#' target='_blank'><img border='0' src='http://www.niftybuttons.com/authentic/color-square/facebook.png'/></a> Hello <a href='www.youtube.com/#' target='_blank'><img border='0' src='http://www.niftybuttons.com/authentic/color-square/youtube.png'/></a> </div>
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IQXD.png]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can use margin property to align your text as you wish

Comment: You know that warning you saw about posting code when linking to jsFiddle? Yeah...that.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/vertical-align

Comment: Could any of you post a jFiddle with your suggestion in action?

Comment: @user3745387 I removed the javascript, blogger, and blogspot tags as they have nothing at all to do with the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve it with

> display: inline:block

and

> vertical-align

HTML (I wrapped your text within a span):

> ```
> <span>Hello</span>
> ```

CSS:

> a, span {vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block;}

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/xE2qJ/1/

Comment: No need to set `display:inline-block` as spans are by default inline! :)

Answer (score 0):

People will flame for this but for such things i prefer to use tables. Easiest way to accomplish vertical alignment.

Another option would be checking for the pictures height and setting line-height + height to that value.

Comment: You don't need to use `<table>` tags to reap the advantages of table-cells, you can use `display:table` and `display: table-cell` as needed.

Comment: why bother using another tag and manipulate it in order to behave like another tag though. that's like building a robot to act and behave like a horse, instead of just getting a horse...

Comment: Sometimes you want the semantics of non-table elements (especially in HTML5) but some of the display properties of table elements (for example, vertical-align).  In some cases, specialty browsers (screen readers) handle table elements differently than other elements since those specialty browsers are expecting tables to display tabulated data.

Comment: That's correct if you're using it to build a page layout. However in most environments you can't rely on Html5 features yet.

anyway - the lineheight+height way is the option i would go for to solve this problem